# Cannot redirect to new page with NodeJS (Express)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

For quite some time, I have been attempting to figure out how to simply redirect the user to a new page on button click with NodeJS and Express. The result of pressing the "Next page" button of the following page (index.html) is the error `Cannot GET /nextpage.html`. When I open the console, I see that the server responded with a 404 error. Both index.html and nextpage.html are stored in the "views" folder. Here is my index.html, server.js, and client.js:

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p>Home</p>
    <a href="nextpage.html" id="button">Next page</a>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require('http')

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get("/", function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

app.get("/next", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/nextpage.html');
});

var listener = app.listen('8080', function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

**client.js**

```
$(function name() {
  
    $('#button').click(function() {
      $.get({url: '/next'}, function(data) {
          console.log("Next page requested.");
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Your route for the `nextpage.html` view is `/next`.

Comment: @tkausl Corrected my post, I still get the same error after updating the get request.

Comment: I don't think `$.get` does what you *think* it does - you might want to review the summary of its functionality on its [documentation page](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). What your function is doing is simply retrieving the contents served at that endpoint and not doing anything with them. This is *completely* different than allowing the `a` tag to move the user's browser to the appropriate page. In this case, don't try to handle the `click` event - just set your `a` tag's `href` attribute properly and allow the link to be followed instead: `<a href="/next" id="button">Next page</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong in HTML.
In HTML your anchor tag href is "nextpage.html" which is not a valid route. So it will throw 404.

Clicking on the anchor tag is doing 2 things

1. Triggering Js onclick event.
2. Default nature(going to href value)

Default nature on redirecting of the anchor will go to 'http://localhost:8080/nextpage.html'

You can solve this like following.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <p>Home</p>
    <a href="/next" id="button">Next page</a>
</html>
```